# Bootstrap + Thumbnail Grid with Expanding Preview

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having issues trying to use this Thumbnail Grid with Expanding Preview with Bootstrap 3 html/css responsive grid :

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

Try to click on different images, images superimpose with the preview :
http://bit.ly/1psqfM2

Anyone encountered the same problem and would have a solution ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if it works - change **.og-grid li** from:

```
width: 25%;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
```

to

```
width: 24%; /* (or just use -box-sizing because current 25% + margin exceed size for 4 columns)  */
float: none;
display: inline-block;
```

More about box-sizing: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Wow thanks, so cool ! With width 24% and float none, pics do not superimpose anymore. Seems the only issue left is the position of the green preview : http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2648-104.html
http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2648-105.html